# Javascript: Get cell's column id

Tags: javascript, html

For example:

I want to accomplish what the following psuedo code does

```
<scipt>
var intCol = document.getElementById('x').column
</scipt>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify.  Providing some HTML would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use `cellIndex`?

On this page:

```
$('.postcell')[0].cellIndex
> 1
$('.votecell')[0].cellIndex
> 0
```

I know people hate W3Schools, but they do provide a good basic dataset:
  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp