# Hide table column based on TD id

Tags: javascript, html

I have one html page with this dynamically generated table and I need to hide the entire columns from certain td ids like "Id_Position", "Id_Equipe" and "Id_Vehicule" with javascript. How do I do that?

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="HeaderRow">
            <td id="Id_Position" align="left" width="25">P</td>
            <td id="Id_Numero" align="left" width="25">No.</td>
            <td id="Id_Perso1" align="left" width="80">Driver</td>
            <td id="Id_Equipe" align="left" width="190">Team</td>
            <td id="Id_Vehicule" align="left" width="60">Model</td>
            <td id="Id_NbTour" align="left" width="25">L</td>
            <td id="Id_TpsCumule" align="left" width="85">Total time</td>
            <td id="Id_VitesseMoyTotal" align="left" width="30">Avg</td>
            <td id="Id_Ecart1er" align="left" width="35">Gap</td>
            <td id="Id_EcartPrec" align="left" width="50">PGap</td>
            <td id="Id_MeilleurTour" align="left" width="50">Best</td>
            <td id="Id_AuTour" align="left" width="25">In</td>
            <td id="Id_Inter1" align="left" width="45">S1</td>
            <td id="Id_MeilleurInter1" align="left" width="45">BS1</td>
            <td id="Id_Inter2" align="left" width="45">S2</td>
            <td id="Id_MeilleurInter2" align="left" width="45">BS2</td>
            <td id="Id_Inter3" align="left" width="45">S3</td>
            <td id="Id_MeilleurInter3" align="left" width="45">BS3</td>
            <td id="Id_TpsTour" align="left" width="50">Laptime</td>
            <td id="Id_NbStand" align="left" width="20">P</td>
            <td id="Id_PositionDepart" align="left" width="20">StartP</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="OddRow">
            <td align="left" class="">1</td>
            <td align="left" class="">65</td>
            <td align="left" class="">MAX</td>
            <td align="left" class="">Eurofarma RC</td>
            <td align="left" class="">Chevrolet</td>
            <td align="left" class="">26</td>
            <td align="left" class="">00:28:06.567</td>
            <td align="left" class="">126.42</td>
            <td align="left" class="">-</td>
            <td align="left" class="">-</td>
            <td align="left" class="">55.487</td>
            <td align="left" class="">23</td>
            <td align="left" class="BestTime">15.572</td>
            <td align="left" class="">15.572</td>
            <td align="left" class="">-</td>
            <td align="left" class="">16.086</td>
            <td align="left" class="">21:55.535</td>
            <td align="left" class="">24.066</td>
            <td align="left" class="">56.208</td>
            <td align="left" class="">0</td>
            <td align="left" class="">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="EvenRow">
            <td align="left" class="">2</td>
            <td align="left" class="">0</td>
            <td align="left" class="">CBU</td>
            <td align="left" class="">Red Bull Racing</td>
            <td align="left" class="">Chevrolet</td>
            <td align="left" class="">26</td>
            <td align="left" class="">00:28:07.910</td>
            <td align="left" class="">126.32</td>
            <td align="left" class="">1.343</td>
            <td align="left" class="">1.343</td>
            <td align="left" class="">55.590</td>
            <td align="left" class="">10</td>
            <td align="left" class="">15.977</td>
            <td align="left" class="">15.711</td>
            <td align="left" class="">-</td>
            <td align="left" class="">16.126</td>
            <td align="left" class="">6:57.520</td>
            <td align="left" class="">24.183</td>
            <td align="left" class="">56.293</td>
            <td align="left" class="">0</td>
            <td align="left" class="">6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JS solution, sourced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754013/hiding-columns-in-table-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360254/javascript-get-cells-column-id). No other markup needed:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  hide();
};

function show_hide_column(col_id, do_show) {
  var stl;
  if (do_show) stl = 'block'
  else stl = 'none';

  var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var index = document.getElementById(col_id).cellIndex;
  var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for (var row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
    var cels = rows[row].getElementsByTagName('td')
    cels[index].style.display = stl;
  }
}


function hide() {
  show_hide_column("Id_Position", false);
  show_hide_column("Id_Equipe", false);
  show_hide_column("Id_Vehicule", false);
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="HeaderRow">
      <td id="Id_Position" align="left" width="25">P</td>
      <td id="Id_Numero" align="left" width="25">No.</td>
      <td id="Id_Perso1" align="left" width="80">Driver</td>
      <td id="Id_Equipe" align="left" width="190">Team</td>
      <td id="Id_Vehicule" align="left" width="60">Model</td>
      <td id="Id_NbTour" align="left" width="25">L</td>
      <td id="Id_TpsCumule" align="left" width="85">Total time</td>
      <td id="Id_VitesseMoyTotal" align="left" width="30">Avg</td>
      <td id="Id_Ecart1er" align="left" width="35">Gap</td>
      <td id="Id_EcartPrec" align="left" width="50">PGap</td>
      <td id="Id_MeilleurTour" align="left" width="50">Best</td>
      <td id="Id_AuTour" align="left" width="25">In</td>
      <td id="Id_Inter1" align="left" width="45">S1</td>
      <td id="Id_MeilleurInter1" align="left" width="45">BS1</td>
      <td id="Id_Inter2" align="left" width="45">S2</td>
      <td id="Id_MeilleurInter2" align="left" width="45">BS2</td>
      <td id="Id_Inter3" align="left" width="45">S3</td>
      <td id="Id_MeilleurInter3" align="left" width="45">BS3</td>
      <td id="Id_TpsTour" align="left" width="50">Laptime</td>
      <td id="Id_NbStand" align="left" width="20">P</td>
      <td id="Id_PositionDepart" align="left" width="20">StartP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="OddRow">
      <td align="left" class="">1</td>
      <td align="left" class="">65</td>
      <td align="left" class="">MAX</td>
      <td align="left" class="">Eurofarma RC</td>
      <td align="left" class="">Chevrolet</td>
      <td align="left" class="">26</td>
      <td align="left" class="">00:28:06.567</td>
      <td align="left" class="">126.42</td>
      <td align="left" class="">-</td>
      <td align="left" class="">-</td>
      <td align="left" class="">55.487</td>
      <td align="left" class="">23</td>
      <td align="left" class="BestTime">15.572</td>
      <td align="left" class="">15.572</td>
      <td align="left" class="">-</td>
      <td align="left" class="">16.086</td>
      <td align="left" class="">21:55.535</td>
      <td align="left" class="">24.066</td>
      <td align="left" class="">56.208</td>
      <td align="left" class="">0</td>
      <td align="left" class="">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="EvenRow">
      <td align="left" class="">2</td>
      <td align="left" class="">0</td>
      <td align="left" class="">CBU</td>
      <td align="left" class="">Red Bull Racing</td>
      <td align="left" class="">Chevrolet</td>
      <td align="left" class="">26</td>
      <td align="left" class="">00:28:07.910</td>
      <td align="left" class="">126.32</td>
      <td align="left" class="">1.343</td>
      <td align="left" class="">1.343</td>
      <td align="left" class="">55.590</td>
      <td align="left" class="">10</td>
      <td align="left" class="">15.977</td>
      <td align="left" class="">15.711</td>
      <td align="left" class="">-</td>
      <td align="left" class="">16.126</td>
      <td align="left" class="">6:57.520</td>
      <td align="left" class="">24.183</td>
      <td align="left" class="">56.293</td>
      <td align="left" class="">0</td>
      <td align="left" class="">6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the code. I'm very sorry for the lame question since I'm not a programmer, but how do I make the code to run without the click on the button, just by loading the page? also, I don't have control of the table source, I'd need to give in ID after is loaded to the page, by javascript i guess, is there a way?

Comment: No problem! Hey, asking questions is how we all learn. :) I updated my post with your requirements. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm :) What is the "[0]" after ('table')? Is to specify only the first table element in case there are others on the page?

Comment: Yup. The `getElementsXxx` functions return an array, so the bracket expression grabs the first array element matched.

Comment: The code works perfectly when I have the table directly on the HTML page, but whenever I load the table with ajax, the 'hide script' doesn't work. Any work around? I wish to be able to manipulate the table after `$(document).ready(Load('p1.html', 'result'));` runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can leverage the col tag the solution, in pure javascript, is straightforward:

```
<table id='id_of_table' border=1>
  <col class="col1"/>
  <col class="col2"/>
  <col class="col3"/>
  <col class="col4"/>
  <tr><td colspan="4"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr>
  <tr><td>  2</td><td>   two</td><td>   deux</td><td>     zwei</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  3</td><td> three</td><td>  trois</td><td>     drei</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  4</td><td>  four</td><td>quattre</td><td>     vier</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  5</td><td>  five</td><td>   cinq</td><td>f&uuml;nf</td></tr>
  <tr><td>  6</td><td>   six</td><td>    six</td><td>    sechs</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can apply to col just a couple of css attributes, but visibility is one of them

```
function show_hide_column(col_no, do_show) {
       var tbl = document.getElementById('id_of_table');
       var col = tbl.getElementsByTagName('col')[col_no];
       if (col) {
         col.style.visibility=do_show?"":"collapse";
       }
    }
```

For Reference: http://www.dotnetlearners.com/javascript/hide%20table%20column%20using%20javascript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Id_Position,#Id_Equipe,#Id_Vehicule").hide();
}
```

Comment: This only hides the header, not the whole column.

Comment: you can hide the table before it is added to the page

Answer (score 0):

```
var header = document.querySelector('#' + yourID),
    index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(header.parentNode.childNodes, header);
header.style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('.OddRow').childNodes[index].style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('.EvenRow').childNodes[index].style.display = 'none';
```

Note: If you are hiding after a click/change/etc event, the event will have a target property that will give you the header node as well, instead of getting it with document.querySelector

Answer (score 0):

not really sure if this is correct, i would find the index of the current col, and apply it to all row.

```
var id = ""; 
var targetEl = document.getElementById(id);
var targetIndex = 0; 

while((targetEl=targetEl.previousSibling)!=null) ++targetIndex;  
// return index of targeted td 

var allRow = document.getElementByTagName('tr')
var rowLength = allRow.length; 

for(i=0; i<rowLength; i++) {
     allRow[i].childNodes[targetIndex].style.display = "none";
}
```